# Angular - removing class after time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a sort of (faux) loader in Angular. Currently, I have this:

```
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('loaderCtrl', ($scope, $timeout) => {
    let loading = $scope.loading,
         loaded = $scope.loaded;

    $scope.reset = () => {
        $timeout(() => {
            loading = false;
            loaded = false;
            console.log(loaded);
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<main ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="loaderCtrl as loader" >
        <div class="loader" ng-class="{ '-loading' : loader.loading === true, '-loaded' : loader.loaded === true }"></div>
        <button ng-click="loader.loading = true;">loading</button>
        <button ng-click="loader.loaded = true; reset();">loaded</button>
    </div>
</main>
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/WrXXdp

My problem is, both `loading` and `loaded` aren't being set up for my view, so the classes are permanently there. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a problem of scope. Basically when you do this

```
let loading = $scope.loading,
    loaded = $scope.loaded;
```

You get the "value" of the variables inside Angular scope. Therefore Angular does not know anything about changes made to those

The fix is simple, don't do that, but instead

```
$scope.reset = () => {
    $timeout(() => {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.loaded = false;
    }, 500);
}
```

Why not using an object and change its content? It is possible to do that as @beaver pointed out, but then you have another problem, you need to trigger the digest cycle yourself via `$apply`. And somewhere in your code, you might accidentally change the content of the object and it might affect other part of the system

Comment: There is no need for $scope.$apply(). It was a typo.

Comment: Great answer, but I had to change ng-clicks from `loader.loading` to `loading` and I'm afraid this may come after me some time in the future.

Comment: @beaver I might be wrong but I think Angular can only check if you change the object reference (not its content). Therefore, if you use an object you need to call the digest cycle manually or somehow tell Angular to check to the object content (instead of reference)

Comment: One more thing though. I will like to move those clicks outsite the controller. They're working good, but I can't trigger `reset()` with that notation (check CodePen for code).

Comment: @Tan Nguyen, in general for Asynchronous calls it is necessary a $scope.$apply(), however $timeout wrapper already do that (and also $http). Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: @TomekBuszewski You should consider this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKOLEa . Basically, you should not put too much logic into your template. Instead, put the logic into separate methods, it will be easier to unit test the directive

Answer (score 1):

Having said that I do not know Babel and so I worked on the JS compiled version, I noticed that you assigned loader.loading and loader.loaded to variables and then used those "references" in $timeout function.

As in javascript

> Primitives are passed by value, Objects are passed by "copy of a
>   reference"

you have to use $scope.loader.loading and $scope.loader.loaded

```
app.controller('loaderCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.loader = {};
    var loading = $scope.loader.loading, loaded = $scope.loader.loaded;
    $scope.reset = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.loader.loading = false;
            $scope.loader.loaded = false;
        }, 500);
    };
});
```

Here I forked your CodePen: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/wMPprm

Comment: Okay, and is there a way to access the `$scope.reset()` outside the controller?

Comment: As `reset` is a function defined in the `$scope` of 'loaderCtrl', it is available in its [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) and in the scope of its children. Where do you need to call it?

Comment: I want to use it as something pretty independent, like when I'll run a `$http` on something like this. Service would be better for this, I think.

Comment: what about to create an Angular directive for your loader?you could be inspired by this https://github.com/victorbjelkholm/ngprogress

Comment: I tried creating a directive just minutes ago, but I want it to be controller-independent and I can't seem to find a way to do this.